# USB works only after reboot windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb

recently my win 7 laptop has had problem. The USB stops responding and doesn't detect anything connected to it, in this case my smartphone in disk drive mode. When I reboot the laptop, it works fine but only after some time has elapsed, the USB no longer detects any device connected to it. My mouse is USB but continues to work without reboot.

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried plugging the smartphone into the port you mouse is plugged into? And vise versa? Sounds simple, but it could be a dodgy port.

If that fails. Try your smartphone in another computer (if you have access to one) and see if it does the same thing.

I've got a galaxy note 2 and it was doing something similar. Found out after trying in another computer that it was my phone causing the problem. Factory reset later and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting hints. The phone doesn't get detected on any of the 3 ports on the laptop. The mouse however, once unplugged and plugged again on any port, doesn't get detected anymore. I'll have to reboot for it to work now.

Comment: Could possibly be an issue with the chip that runs your USB ports. If not then might be worth installing your motherboards chipset drivers again. Usually if it's a windows PC and fairly new you can grab the chipset drivers direct from intel or AMD.

Comment: Just checked there are no updated usb drivers on manufacturers support website. Thanks.

Comment: Darn it! Random thought. Try the same in safe mode. If it works then it could be something else interfering with USB during normal operation. If it doesn't work then I would maybe try a system restore to a point where you knew it was working. Just in case windows installed a driver update that might be causing the problem.

Comment: same thing is safe mode.

Comment: Give good old system restore a bash. It could be a long shot but might just do the trick. If that doesn't work and you've re-installed the chipset drivers for your motherboard then could be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Plug your device into your computer and go to: `Start > Computer (Right click) > Manage > Device Manager`.  Is your device displayed in the device manager?  Does it have a yellow exclamation point next to the detected device in the drop down menu?  If it has a yellow exclamation point, right click, uninstall, re-plug the device back into the computer, bottom right on the taskbar should display Windows re-installing the usb driver.

Comment: No, the device is not displayed in DM when plugged into USB. So the rest of your advice cannot be used. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Go to the make/model of your pc's website and the usb drivers for your pc.  Or you can also go to the manufacture of your phone's website and see if there is software for the phone to install the phone's drivers so that it becomes detected.  Check for windows update (optional included) to see if there are any drivers that need to be installed for usb.

Comment: Do you have admin Rights? Ive seen driver problems for usb devices when they were installed by somebody other than the admin. I know it sounds crazy,  but i've seen stranger things.