# Frontal USB recognized only after reboot

Tags: windows-8, usb

**The problem**

USB devices that are plugged in the frontal pane of my PC are not recognized by Windows unless I reboot.

After reboot, USB devices get recognized until the next shutdown. The rear USB ports do not suffer from this problem.

**My specs**

- Motherboard: MSI H55M-E33
- OS: Windows 8.1 Update 1 (but it had the same behaviour on Windows 8 and 8.1, while it didn't on Windows 7)

The problem doesn't exist with another PC I have at home.

**What have i tried with no success**

- Changing USB power saving setting
- Full format and re-installation of Windows
- Checking BIOS settings
- Checking Device Manager for possible errors, but none found
- Downloading all possible up-to-date drivers for my motherboard

The thing is, I don't think it's an hardware problem because frontal USB ports work with no problem on Windows 7.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/554564/usb-works-only-after-reboot-windows-7) is similar but in that case the OP's USB devices stopped working after some time, which is not my case. Also he was using Windows 7, which works fine for me.